# Finite Summation identity involving Kronecker Delta

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to establish a proof for $(1)$ hints appreciated thanks.

$\forall (n,N) \in \Bbb N^2\,\land a \gt 1,b \gt 1$

$(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$

$$\delta \left( x,y \right) =\cases{1&$x=y$\cr 0&$x\neq y$\cr}\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{                             (0)}$$

$$\sum _{k=1}^{ N} \left( 
\delta \left( n,k \right) -b\delta \left( n,k+1 \right)  \right) 
 \Bigl\lfloor{a\,{b}^{k-  N}} \Bigr\rfloor=\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad                         $$
$$(1-\delta \left( N,0 \right))\Biggl(\Bigl\lfloor{a\,{b}^{\,n-  {N}  }} \Bigr\rfloor-(1-\delta \left( n,1 \right))b\Bigl\lfloor{a\,{b}^{\,n-  {N}  -1}} \Bigr\rfloor-\delta \left( n,N+1 \right)a\,b\Biggr)\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{                             (1)}$$

Comment: I recommend also using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), in terms of which $\delta(x,\,y)=[x=y]$. In (1), the left-hand side is$$[1\le n\le N]\left\lfloor ab^{n-N}\right\rfloor-b[2\le n\le N+1]\left\lfloor ab^{n-N-1}\right\rfloor$$while the right-hand side is$$[N\ne0]\left\lfloor ab^{n-N}\right\rfloor-b[N\ne0,\,n\ne 1]\left\lfloor ab^{n-N-1}\right\rfloor-ab[N\ne 0,\,n=N+1].$$Can you take it from there?

Comment: I don't see how this makes any difference, it's just restating things

Comment: I have had a look, and I just don't quite see how these brackets supply proof of identities, I feel as if they are just restating the identity itself, and can definitely see the convenience in regard the system the author made for remainders of certain principles, but I don't see what's being proven by using them

Comment: reminders* of certain conventions*